# Contact form 7 Datepicker, different 2 dates

Tags: jquery, wordpress, date, datepicker, contact-form-7

I have two date field in my Wordpress contact form 7. A check-in-date and an check-out-date. The fields will be datepickers from the "Contact Form 7 Datepicker" plugin. When visitor has selected a check-in-date he should only be able to select the check-out-date that is 1 day later then the check-in-date selected by the user.

I tried using the reference of [Contact form 7 Datepicker, date range between 2 dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18515921/contact-form-7-datepicker-date-range-between-2-dates) but didn't help -

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I don't understand...What's the point of a second datepicker if it's always going to be start date + 1?

Comment: It's like a start date and end date of a reservation. you can have a look at it http://liveingoa.in/property/sea-view-wooden-beach-cottage-in-vagator-goa/

Answer (score 0):

Please can you use this example that you mentioned it above but open browser console and let me what is the output :

```
        Start date charter*:
        [date* date-start date-format:MM_d_yy]

        End date charter*:
        [date* date-end date-format:MM_d_yy]
        And I added this code to the end of the functions file of the Wordpress theme.

        function calendar_js(){
        ?>
        <script>
        jQuery(function($){
        var start = $('.date-start input').first();
        var end = $('.date-end input').first();

        start.on('change', function() {
        var start_date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        start_date.setDate(start_date.getDate() + 3);
        console.log(start_date.getDate());
        end.datepicker('option', 'minDate', start_date);
        });
        });
        </script>
        <?php
        }
        add_action('wp_footer', 'calendar_js');
```

Comment: what was the output ?!

Comment: It didn't work out I'm still able to select the end-date as same as the start-date. While the code should **NOT** allow a user to select the end-date the same as the start date.

Comment: please click f12 and go to console and copy results and paste it here , so i can help you

Comment: There are no errors in the console, you can have a look at the website http://liveingoa.in/property/beach-cottage-in-morjim-goa/

Comment: please copy the above code and replace it with your current script

Answer (score 0):

After searching & trying & trying a lot (I'm completly newbee in coding),
I paste this code at the end of the CF7+CF7datepicker form
fullfilled like this:
arrival id:date1           (set to min-date:0)
departure id:date2     (must be 1 day ahead arrival date)
And miraculously, it finally work. Hope that it can help.

Code:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $("#date1").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        onSelect    : function (selected) {
            var unique = $(this).attr('id');
            unique = unique.replace('date1', '');
            var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            if (date) {
                date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
            }
            $( '#date2' + unique).datepicker( 'option', 'minDate', date)
        }
    });
});
```